# Remove features in Microsoft Office 365 Home Premium Preview

Tags: windows-8, office365

I installed **Microsoft Office 365 Home Premium Preview** and it automatically installed some apps that I don't need like Publisher, OneNote, etc.

How can I remove the extra apps that I don't need? I try the *Change* option in Control panel but there's no way to remove separate apps in the bundle. When I click on Change it will only let me repair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After quickly installing Office 365 Home Premium Preview, I have come to the conclusion that it doesn't have the option to install/remove individual components, either from within the Programs and Features control panel, or from the [online account manager](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/MyAccount.aspx).

So, it does not appear to be possible to remove individual components from Office 365 Home Premium at this time.

---

(The question previously referred to Office 2013 Preview, which is somewhat different. The answer for Office 2013 Preview was:)

After you click **Change** in the Control Panel, the first thing you should see is a dialog asking what you want to do. Choose **Add or Remove Features**.

[image]

Next, you'll be presented with a list of the installed programs. To remove one, click the down arrow and you'll get a menu. Change the selection to **Not Available**. Once you've finished, click Continue, and the components will be uninstalled.

[image]

Comment: when I click change there's only 2 options: Quick repair and Online repair. There's no remove feature option

Comment: @Chin You don't want to choose Repair. You want to choose Add or Remove Features. I've expanded the answer.

Comment: when I click on change, the repair dialog pop up so I can't choose the option like in your image

Comment: @Chin Perhaps you should repair it first. :)

Comment: btw, it's shown as "Microsoft Office 365 Home Premium Preview", unlike yours. So maybe it's a different thing?

Comment: @Chin Yes, that's a somewhat different piece of software. Perhaps you should edit your question. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Yet another Microsoft failure.

See e.g. "If you have Office 365 you cannot uninstall individual applications" (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-onenote/how-do-i-uninstall-onenote-from-office-2013/2fb1f12d-7cc5-4004-8b39-d0f4d22d84da)

Someone on that page did mention that it (which he calls "App Exclusion" during installation) is coming.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

Probably not a great idea, but you could of course delete various files, such as:

• C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\ONENOTE.EXE
• C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\ONENOTEM.EXE (that annoying "Send to OneNote" item in the tray)

A temporary workaround, I know, but at least this way they won't pop up and annoy you.